# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Any idea why i am getting this; currently i m trying to add the SQlDependency.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Switch from Windows to SQL Authentication.

Steps include:

1. Right click server name and select properties.
2. Then select Security tab.
3. Enable sql server and windows authentication mode
4. Restart Sql server service

Try login again.

Also you can try restarting Sql server from services tab